# Rubocop - disable long length for commented code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

Don't know why but rubocop takes the length of the line in the comment and show we an error:

```
config/initializers/devise.rb:116:121: C: Layout/LineLength: Line is too long. [150/120]
  # config.secret_key = '0cfe0f176132fc4ef87b7fc01d8e65b31a74d3e41d5df18cccd20d1a65f447a28d41744cf8ed9e99a704c449f930673f297fe2ee4dbffa7c7162ba24baa5359a'
                                                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Should I disable it in `.rubocop.yml` somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Layout/LineLength:
  Max: 150 (for example)
```

or disable this cop at all

```
Layout/LineLength:
  Enabled: false
```

or there is an option to ignore lines which start from certain character:

```
Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 80
  IgnoredPatterns: ['(\A|\s)#']
```

Comment: IgnoredPatterns seems to have been replaced by AllowedPatterns. Not really sure how to handle that now.

Comment: I don't understand why `IgnoredPatterns` was renamed `AllowedPatterns`, the words Ignored and Allowed have opposite meaning.

Comment: @DavidCruwys rubocop is a *cop* that looks for *offences*. For this context, anything ignored by it is effectively allowed, so it isn't the opposite meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is now obsolete because Rubocop questionably changed `IgnoredPatterns` to `AllowedPatterns`.

The following configuration worked for me:

```
Layout/LineLength:
  AllowedPatterns: ['^(\s*#)']
```

This regex only works when the entire line is commented out. Code followed by a long comment on the same line will still trigger a Rubocop lint error, which is by design.